# Obtain Class instances in a directory from URLClassLoader

Tags: java, junit, classloader

I need to load some test classes in a specified directory to run junit test that they contain.
Seems I'm having some problem with method `Class.forName()` and an `URLClassLoader`.

I have some Junit test class in a folder whose path is
`C:\Documents\Java\Project\src\tests\net\sourceforge`
and compiled classes in
`C:\Documents\Java\Project\target\tests-classes\net\sourceforge`

I need to have instances of `Class` for run `JunitCore.run()` but when I try to use the `Class.forName()` method i get a `NoClassDefFoundException` or a `ClassNotFoundException`.

What I do currently is iterating over all files within `target\tests-classes\` and trying to load these classes. 
Directory tree structure is something like

```
 SOURCEFILES
- Java
    - Project
        - src
            - tests
                - net
                    - sorceforge
                        - Test1.java
                        - Test2.java
                        - directory1
                            - Test3.java
                            - Test4.java
                        - directory2
                            - Test5.java


 BINARIES
- Java
    - Project
        - target
            - tests-classes
                - net
                    - sorceforge
                        - Test1.class
                        - Test2.class
                        - directory1
                            - Test3.class
                            - Test4.class
                        - directory2
                            - Test5.class
```

Here is the method of my code:

```
 private void runJunitTest(JUnitCore junit, ArrayList<File> directories, String path) {
        File f = new File(path); //path first call is usually "C:\Documents\Java\Project\src\tests\"
        File bin = new File(txtClassTest.getText()); //bin path is "C:\Documents\Java\Project\target\tests-classes\"
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if(files[i].isFile()){
                String fullname = getFullyQualifiedName(files[i].getAbsolutePath(), txtTest.getText()); //getFullyQualifiedName return the fully qualified name of a class eg. net.sourceforge.Test1
                try {
                    URLClassLoader urlClassloader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { bin.toURI().toURL() });
                    Class cl = Class.forName(fullname, false, urlClassloader);
                    Result result = junit.run(cl);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                directories.add(files[i]);
            }
        }
        if(!directories.isEmpty()){
            String dir =  directories.get(0).getAbsolutePath();
            directories.remove(0);
            runJunitTest(junit, directories,dir);
        }
    }       
}
```

I've tried also to change the `bin` and `path` variables to dive inner or go outer of the path but results are pretty the same.

**EDIT**

having `bin`: `...\target\test-classes\`
Here is the exception you asked:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/pmd/ReportListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at elaborationSystem.Interface$ButtonHandler.runJunitTest(Interface.java:386)
    at elaborationSystem.Interface$ButtonHandler.runJunitTest(Interface.java:402)
    at elaborationSystem.Interface$ButtonHandler.runJunitTest(Interface.java:402)
    at elaborationSystem.Interface$ButtonHandler.runJunitTest(Interface.java:402)
    at elaborationSystem.Interface$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(Interface.java:364)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.pmd.ReportListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: *Seeems I'm having some problem*: **Which** problem?

Comment: I've explained in the rest of the question: the `forName` method give me a `ClassNotFoundException` and I cannot obtain the istance of `Class` that I need. So I think that probably I'm settin the wrong path for the URLClassLoader. But i really don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Post the complete exception stack trace.

Comment: So, it seems that the class that is not found is not one of your test classes, but a class used by one of your test classes. The jars/directories containing these used classes should also be in the URLs of the URLClassLoader. Or they should be in your application classpath, and the classloader of your application should be the parent of the URLClassLoader that you create (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#newInstance%28java.net.URL[],%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I've added classes and jar imported in tests and application start working. If you want to post your comment as answer I'll accept it.